# Concatenating two variables into a single variable

Tags: arrays, vb.net, concatenation

I am loading a txt file that I can split each row into an array (using "|" as the delimiter) using the split function.

However each row has a different number of elements within the array, so I cannot make a 2D array.

I'd like to somehow be able to combine a text string and an integer into a new variable.

```
    Dim i As Integer = 0

    Dim "row" & i As String = StringinRowi
```

To give

```
row0 = StringinRow0
```

And then loop this as many times as there are lines within the text file (I got this figured out)

Is this at all possible?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: you have already declared i as integer and redfining as string?

Comment: No, not the way you want.

Comment: Could you supply a sample of the data from the text file?

Answer (score 0):

A 2D array might not work but a 2D List would work.  Declare the list,

```
Dim data As New List(Of List(Of String))
```

Then cast the Split return .ToList.

```
data.Add(readlinestring.Split("|"c).ToList)
```

Now each row will be an index of `data` and will contain a list of strings also indexed.
Since everything is indexed, this should obviate the need for numbered variables.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `DataTable`. They're awesome.

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim dtbData As New DataTable

    Dim strFilename As String = "C:\Junk\Junk.txt"
    Using sr As New StreamReader(strFilename)
      Do Until sr.EndOfStream
        Dim strLine As String = sr.ReadLine()
        Dim strFields() As String = Split(strLine, "|")
        For i As Integer = dtbData.Columns.Count To strFields.GetUpperBound(0) 'add new columns if necessary
          dtbData.Columns.Add("Column" + i.ToString)
        Next i
        dtbData.Rows.Add(strFields)
      Loop
      MsgBox("Row 2 Column 1 = " & dtbData.Rows(1).Item("Column1").ToString)
    End Using

  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You can just use an integer value instead of `"Column1"` if you prefer. Just remember to start counting from `0`, not `1`.

Comment: It would be better to use a `Do Until sr.EndOfStream` `Loop` rather than checking the string each time